# Deleting content of a std::list

Tags: c++, c++11, doubly-linked-list, stdlist

I have a list of pointers which I don't need anymore. To delete all of them, I can normally iterate the list:

```
for (T* ptr: mylist) {
    delete ptr;
}
```

Or I can delete the first or last element until the list is empty:

```
while (!mylist.empty()) {
    delete mylist.front(); //or mylist.back()
    mylist.pop_front(); //or mylist.pop_back()
}
```

What is the preferred way, both for performance and  clarity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way is to store `std::unique_ptr's` in list and not manage memory yourself. Then you just do `mylist.clear()`.

Comment: `std::list::clear` is completely new to me lal. Good suggestion however.

Comment: Please note, that `clear` will remove all elements from the list. Smart pointers upon removal will also free memory which they hold. But usual pointers will not. So this method works only with smart pointers. Anyway, nowdays manually deleting objects is considered a bad practice because it is too error prone.

Comment: Good to know that last bit. Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 3):

I would use your first example. For best practice you should clear your list afterwards to ensure no invalid pointers are left in it.

```
for (T* ptr : mylist) delete ptr;
mylist.clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

They do two different things. The second leaves you with an empty list. The first leaves you with a list that holds a bunch of invalid pointers; that may or may not matter, depending on what happens to the list after this operation.